# Repeating the background when touches began in Spritkit

Tags: swift, background, sprite-kit, horizontal-scrolling, touchesbegan

I have a simple code that repeats the background for ever using Spritekit, i want the background to be still before any touches occur and only start animating or scrolling when any touches began

```
    *// animate the background*

    let background = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")

    let moveTheBackground = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: -
    background.size().width, dy:0),  duration: 10)

    let backgroundToOriginalPosition = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: 
    background.size().width, dy: 0), duration: 0)

    let animateTheBackground = 
    SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([moveTheBackground, 
    backgroundToOriginalPosition]))


    *// loop the background animation*

    var i:CGFloat = 0
    while i < 2 {

        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: background)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: background.size().width * i, y: self.frame.midY)
        bg.size.height = self.frame.height
        bg.zPosition = -1
        bg.run(animateTheBackground)
        self.addChild(bg)

        i += 1
    }
```

i want this code to happen when touchesbegan in SpriteKit, 
any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In any game programming, ideal way to show horizontal scrolling is use 2 background image and add one after one in horizontal. Move both and whenever background1 cross leftmost 0(in right to left scroll) change its position to width as x. Use main game loop to increment both backgrounds position. In your case use one flag named allowScroll, set this true when touchesBegin. If allowScroll set true then increment/decrement background image positions in game loop.

Comment: Thank you very much Guru,
Lets say i got the above code, its simple , its working all done
i want it to run in touchesbegan method so when someone touches the screen the background starts animating from right to left
before any touches happen the background should be still, not moving and when the screen touched the background should start moving 
how can i make that happen ? thanks

Comment: @mue, you are answering your own question in your question.  Put the run code in your touches began event

Comment: Knight0fDragon, 
i already did, by putting the code in touchesBegan method the background disapeare as its no longer available on didMove(to view: SKView) function, what i want is the background available when game loads and when i touch the screen the background should move to the left infinitly

Comment: @mue, add background image to self as child in init method and do run action in touchesBegin method. Make sure you made instance of background as class member.

Answer (score 0):

Put the code for moving inside of your touchesMoved function to get the background to move correspondingly to the touches